# mysql_connect() - Not working, probably a small error, but I just can't figure out what it is?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stumped. I run the script, no errors are shown, but neither is data inserted into the DB.

Here's my code:

```
include("db_con.php");
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $urls[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url_' . $i]);
    $names[$i] = !empty($_POST['name_' . $i]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name_' . $i]) : mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url_' . $i]);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM multi_url";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$page_id = $num_rows++;

$query2 = "INSERT INTO multi_url (page_id, url_1, url_2, url_3, url_4, url_5, name_1, name_2, name_3, name_4, name_5) values ($page_id, $urls[1], $urls[2], $urls[3], $urls[4], $urls[5], $names[1], $names[2], $names[3], $names[4], $names[5])"; 

mysql_close($conn);
```

Any comments on the matter would be greatly appreciated. If there's a problem, I would've thought I'd get an error from `die(mysql_error())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not send any `INSERT` query to the database. You just put the SQL in a variable called `$query2`.

```
mysql_query($query2); //sends the query to the database
```

That query will fail though, since none of its string columns are enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I completely forgot that strings need to be encased in quotes. You've really been a big help to me, always giving great feedback to my questions!

Comment: I am compelled to mention that this is not a normalised database schema. You model one-to-many relationships (1 page, 0 to N names/urls) with a second table having the page_id as a foreign key. Insert one row per associated name/url. If you ever have a set of identical columns you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: How then would I go about matching one page_id to 5 rows of data? I would've thought placing the page_id in the same row as the urls/names (5 times over in this case), and then searching for all the rows that have the same page_id, but you mentioned a second table?

Comment: The other table would have 3 columns, (page_id, name, url). `SELECT name, url FROM othertable WHERE page_id = ?`.